# PyQt wierd behavior with Multiprocessing.pool

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, python-multiprocessing

Currently I'm trying to start a pool inside a thread, inside this pool i will be creating instances of Qt's QWebEnginePage.

Two things are happening which arn't suppose to be happening.

First:

the way it's iterating thru the list isn't accurate(either it's skipping over some entries or it's not sorted(not sure how it wouldn't be))

Second:

The loop hangs, meaning that everything stops and there doesn't seem to be anything I can do about it.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process

from threading import Thread
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Webkit(QWebEnginePage):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication([])

        super(Webkit, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.pageFinishedLoading)

    def loadUrl(self, url):
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec()

    def pageFinishedLoading(self):
        self.app.quit()

def first():
    """Thread + Process"""
    #Thread(target=lambda: Process(target=second().foo()).start(), daemon=False).start()

    """Thread"""
    Thread(target=second().foo()).start()

    """Process"""
    #Process(target=second().foo()).start()


class second:
    def foo(self):
        count = 10

        print("Starting pool")
        with Pool(1) as pool:
            pool.map(final, range(count))

        print("Starting process")
        for x in range(count):
            p = Process(target=final, args=(x, ))
            p.start()
            p.join()

        print("Finished")

def final(a):
    print("Now creating webkit", a)
    wk = Webkit()
    wk.loadUrl("https://google.com")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    first()

    app.exec()
```

Output:

```
Starting pool
Now creating webkit 0
Now creating webkit 1
Now creating webkit 3
Now creating webkit 4
Now creating webkit 6
Now creating webkit 7
Now creating webkit 9
```

Expected output:

```
Starting pool
Now creating webkit 0
Now creating webkit 1
Now creating webkit 2
Now creating webkit 3
Now creating webkit 4
Now creating webkit 5
Now creating webkit 6
Now creating webkit 7
Now creating webkit 8
Now creating webkit 9

Starting process
Now creating webkit 0
Now creating webkit 1
Now creating webkit 2
Now creating webkit 3
Now creating webkit 4
Now creating webkit 5
Now creating webkit 6
Now creating webkit 7
Now creating webkit 8
Now creating webkit 9

Finished
```

Edit: The for loop works it's just the pool that's broken

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out any real solutions, so i made a hack for it, it isn't pretty but it does the job almost as well as a normal pool should. It creates an extra process for each process which means it will use extra memory, but other then that it should be ok.

If anyone has any better solutions, please post them :)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, starmapstar
import itertools

def caller(func, *args):
    try: length = len(*args)
    except TypeError: length = 1
    p = mp.Process(target=func, args=tuple(*args) if length > 1 else (*args, ))
    p.start()
    return p.join()  # This will only return None



class NoDaemonProcess(mp.Process):
    # make 'daemon' attribute always return False
    def _get_daemon(self):
        return False
    def _set_daemon(self, value):
        pass
    daemon = property(_get_daemon, _set_daemon)


class MyPool(Pool):
    Process = NoDaemonProcess

    def _map_async(self, func, iterable, mapper, chunksize=None, callback=None, error_callback=None):
        iterable = zip(itertools.repeat(func), iterable)
        mapper = starmapstar
        func = caller
        return super(MyPool, self)._map_async(func, iterable, mapper, chunksize, callback, error_callback)
```